# I'm expecting a return type of char, but getting int

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

can anyone tell me why this returns a type of int?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTableExists] @TableName char(40), @Exists char(5) OUTPUT  
AS

IF object_id(@TableName) is not null
    select @Exists = 'true'
ELSE
    select @Exists = 'false'
```

Comment: because you haven't specified what it returns?...

Comment: Why are you using a procedure to return a single value? That's exactly what functions are designed to do, and you can specifically specify the return type.

Comment: @KenWhite To call it from C#.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You didn't make that clear in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of @Exists parameter datatype being "char(5)".

Char must be used when data has a fixed lenght.

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTableExists] @TableName varchar(40), @Exists varchar(5) OUTPUT  
AS

SET @Exists = 'false'
IF object_id(@TableName) is not null
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName) AND type in (N'U'))
    BEGIN
    SET @Exists = 'true'
    END
ELSE
    SET @Exists = 'false'

SELECT @Exists
```

Comment: This may work, but you failed to answer the question asked, which was "Why does my procedure return an int when I'm expecting a char?".

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a `set nocount on` statement, it is returning a row count.  Since it doesn't return any other result, it just does an assignment, that is all you get.